# Tensorflow CNN for different input size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to make conv network for image regression.

As shown in below, one image [224 x 224] has one GT value {x}.

It's easy to make train [224 x 224] and valid/test with [224 x 224] images.

However, I'd like to apply CNN for different image sizes.

For example, [224 x 229] image, I want to get 5 regression values 'at once'.

Simply, I can do that by just sliding windows of [224 x 224] x 5 times, but apparently it is too slow.

I think using conv for different image size is possible. But FCL is not.

If I change image size to [455 x 256]

```
lhs shape= [4608,1024] rhs shape= [2048,1024]
```

error occurred. Is there any way to handle it?

[image]

Comment: What's the error? And please add [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code. And note that in FCL you can not feed different input size. Input size should be fixed first. because different inputs make different number of trainable variables. But in Conv layers, the input can be vary in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully connected layers have a fixed size input. Thus, changing the input size will cause a wrong-size error.

One way to tackle this problem, and allow for different image sizes is to use a [fully convolutional network](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-a-fully-convolutional-network-fcn-in-tensorflow-2-3c46fb61de3b).

### An example with easy numbers:

Assuming for example the conv layer's output is of size 16X16, you can create a "classifier layer" of size 4x4 with stride 4, that would output for each of the 4 4x4 squares comprising the 16x16 feature map, a single value per dimension. Such filter would be of size 4x4xn_dim, in your case n_dim will be 5, and the final output would be of size 4x4x5, corresponding to 5 outputs (one for each regression value) for each 4x4 square.

You will notice you can play with the shape of the last conv filter to obtain different sizes for the final output, corresponding to different parts of the input image, but really, looking at all of it.

You can work out the numbers for your own example.

---

You probably would like to read about basic methods for [semantic segmentaion](https://towardsdatascience.com/semantic-image-segmentation-using-fully-convolutional-networks-bf0189fa3eb8).

Also see [basic fully conv nets](https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/fcn.html).